# How to fix Method does not override any method from its superclass error with UITextViewDelegate on Swift?

Tags: swift, uitextview, overriding

I'm trying to override the textView shouldInteractWithURL method to handle clickable link. So I created a subclass inherited from UITextView and UITextViewDelegate call MyTextView and pending to override the method with this code:

```
import UIKit

class MyTextView: UITextView, UITextViewDelegate {

    override func textView(textView: UITextView!, shouldInteractWithURL URL: NSURL!, inRange characterRange: NSRange) -> Bool {

        println(URL)
        return false
    }
}
```

But I got an error message: Method does not override any method from its superclass.

How to fix that? Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Delegating Objective-C Protocol on Swift](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24699567/delegating-objective-c-protocol-on-swift)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not subclass UITextView. You should implement and add the delegate instead.

```
class MyViewController : UIViewController, UITextViewDelegate {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        var textView = UITextView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, view.frame.width, view.frame.height))
        textView.delegate = self
        view.addSubview(textView)
    }

    // MARK: UITextViewDelegate
    func textView(textView: UITextView!, shouldInteractWithURL URL: NSURL!, inRange characterRange: NSRange) -> Bool {
        println(URL)
        return false
    }
}
```

Comment: I was neither critiquing or requesting clarification. It was an answer to the question but I agree that the answer was to short :)